# Why @Resource can't work in HttpServlet?

Tags: spring, servlets, resources, annotations

I am tiro to `Spring`, and want to use auto wire with annotation `@Resource` in my servlet.
In `service layer` and `dao layer`, this annotation works well, when I use it in my `Servlet`, the exception comes:

```
com.fruit.action.merchant.MerAdd.service name='merAddService' is an unknown @Resource
```

as you see, `MerAdd` is a servlet extends my own `BaseServlet` which extends `HttpServlet`,  `service` is an object of `MerAddServie`, in `MerAdd` servlet:

```
    @Resource(name="merAddService")
private MerAddBusiness service;
public MerAddBusiness getService() {
    return service;
}

public void setService(MerAddBusiness service) {
    this.service = service;
}
```

Is there anything I should do to fix this problem, mybe I misunderstand `@Resource`, can you help me , thanks ahead~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately You cannot autowire using @Resource annotaion in Servlet.
Same Question is discussed in this spring forum [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?64779-Resource-in-Servlet)

**Problem**:-*"The problem here is that some J2EE components have dependencies injected into them by the web container. Which means that @Resource() annotations won't work -- the container will try to resolve those dependencies to JNDI (or somewhere else)."*

**Possible Workaround**:- 
As you can use @Autowired  annotation  in your servlet
So You can delegate request processing to the dedicated bean which will have @Resource Bean autowired in it , i.e. make your servlet to be just an entry point that conforms to the API supported by servlet container. Hence, you can configure that actual business logic holder bean as necessary via spring and just retrieve it from IoC container and call necessary method from the servlet